# how to expand and collapse views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

How to expand on clicking view(orange color) and collapse on clicking the same view or other view

like  in this image :

[image: screen]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to move a view with animation to cover the other view. Something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    view1.frame = CGRectOffset(view1.frame, 0, 250); 
}];
```

You will have to change the frame size/position to reach the position of the other view.